DB2 backup from Data Studio throws sqlcode=-22212
When I try to back up a database, the process fails with the error:
Attempt to connect to DAS failed with the following error: sqlcode=SQL22212N 

db2dasrrm.exe runs under the PID from the netstat entry that shows listening port 523 for svchost. A firewall rule exists that allows DB2DAS - DB2DAS00 service to listen to UDP on that port. I tried to create a replica of that rule for TCP but still got the same error. Tried to restart all DB2 services and to restart the machine to no avail.
The full command is:
CONNECT TO "db1";
QUIESCE DATABASE IMMEDIATE FORCE CONNECTIONS;
CONNECT RESET;
DEACTIVATE DATABASE "db1";
BACKUP DATABASE "db1" TO "C:\Users\me\Documents" COMPRESS EXCLUDE LOGS WITHOUT PROMPTING;
CONNECT TO "db1";
UNQUIESCE DATABASE;
CONNECT RESET;

What do I have to do to successfully back up this database?
